# Not able to upload file to Django server from Service Worker in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob, service-worker, multipartform-data

**This is the code in my background-worker.js file which is supposed to be responsible for uploading the blob**

```
const addExerciseDataToDatabase = async (blob, exercise, patient, authToken) => {
    const databaseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/exercise_record/';

    const fileName = 'video.webm';
    const file = new File([blob], fileName, { type: blob.type });

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('date', getDateWithFormat());
    formData.append('exercise', exercise);
    formData.append('patient', patient);
    formData.append('blob', file);

    const headers = new Headers({
        'Authorization': `Token ${authToken}`,
        'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
    });

    try {
        const response = await fetch(databaseURL, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers,
            body: formData,
        });

        if (response.ok) {
            console.log('Data Added to Database');
        } else {
            console.error('Failed to add data to the database:', response);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error while making the request:', error);
    }
};


// Listen for messages from the main script
this.addEventListener('message', async (event) => {
    const data = event.data;
    if (data.blob) {
        let blob = data.blob;
        console.log(blob);

        try {
            // await uploadFileFirebase(blob);
            await addExerciseDataToDatabase(blob, data.exercise, data.patient, data.authToken)

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
});


const getDateWithFormat = () => {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
    var month = String(currentDate.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
    var day = String(currentDate.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    var formattedDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
    return formattedDate
}
```

**This is my model in django**

```py
class ExerciseRecord(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='exercise_records')
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='exercise_records')
    date = models.DateField()
    video = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', null=True, blank=True)
    review = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True)
    commment = models.TextField(blank=True)
    blob = models.FileField(upload_to='exercise_records/', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.patient} - {self.exercise} - {self.date}'
```

```
class ExerciseRecordViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = ExerciseRecord.objects.all()
serializer_class = ExerciseRecordSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    if hasattr(self.request.user, "patient"):
        return ExerciseRecord.objects.filter(patient__user=self.request.user)
    elif hasattr(self.request.user, "fittlyf_physio"):
        patient_id = self.request.query_params.get("patient_id")
        exercise_record_id = self.request.query_params.get("exercise_record_id")

        if patient_id:
            return ExerciseRecord.objects.filter(patient__id=patient_id)
        if exercise_record_id:
            return ExerciseRecord.objects.filter(id=exercise_record_id)

def perform_create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print(request.data)

    patient_exercises_ids = [
        patient_exercise.exercise.id
        for patient_exercise in PatientExercise.objects.filter(
            patient=request.data["patient"]
        )
    ]

    today_completed_exercise_ids = [
        exercise_record.exercise.id
        for exercise_record in ExerciseRecord.objects.filter(
            date=request.data["date"], patient=request.data["patient"]
        )
    ]

    completed_all_exercises = set(patient_exercises_ids) == set(
        today_completed_exercise_ids
    )
    if completed_all_exercises:
        patient_id = request.data["patient"]
        patient = Patient.objects.get(pk=patient_id)
        patient.completed_exercise_date = date.today()
        patient.save()

    serializer = ExerciseRecordSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**The response that I receive in terminal:-**

```
Bad Request: /exercise_record/
```

[13/Oct/2023 10:02:54] "POST /exercise_record/ HTTP/1.1" 400 77

Blob {size: 64688, type: 'video/webm;codecs=vp8'}

this is how the blob looks in console

```
background-worker.js:51 Failed to add data to the database: Response {type: 'cors', url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/exercise_record/', redirected: false, status: 400, ok: false, …}
addExerciseDataToDatabase @ background-worker.js:51
await in addExerciseDataToDatabase (async)
(anonymous) @ background-worker.js:67
```

I get some this kind of response

Please help me with this and let me know what am I doing wrong, Everything is correct in the backend I am sure about that as rest endpoints responsible for file uploading works but not this one

**When I remove the content-type from the headers this is what I get at print(request.data) at the viewset. Everything thing works fine except that the blob is empty**

```
{'date': '2023-10-13', 'video': None, 'review': False, 'blob': None, 'patient': 80, 'exercise': 12}
```

Comment: 1) Please post the route handling code from your Django app. 2) What happens if you try to POST to the server using a CURL command?  What response do you get in the terminal?  BTW you should add this info to your QUESTION, not here in a comment.

Comment: I have mentioned the viewset that gets hit at that endpoint

Answer (score 0):

I see that your backend endpoint in this code is also local, so if you set the django DEBUG=True in your local settings file, you probably can get a better hint about what’s going on from your Django stdout/logs.

Could it be the same problem that is mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70970333/django-multipart-form-data-pass-dict-file)?

Also I think it would be helpful if you also share the `ExerciseRecordSerializer` in your question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why but when I commented the def perform_create() function then everything works, there is something in that function with makes the blob vanish.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).